# Place text over image with fixed height

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-theme-astra

I'm new to WordPress and am using the Astra theme with the standard Gutenberg builder. It would be great to be able to have a text that can be placed over an image like on this [website](https://websitedemos.net/fitness-trainer-04/):
[image: example]

The green square image should be placed behind the text:
[image: square]

With the standard `Cover` block it scales the height of the image too large, see second picture. When using `Media and text` block, the text can't be placed over the image.

I tried using the `Spectra` plugin of Astra to get this done, but can't seem to find a way. Another idea was to set a fixed height for a `Column` and place the `Cover` in there. But the object `Column` only has `Minimal height` and not `Fixed height`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding an additional CSS class to the **paragraph** within the Cover block, you can use `clip-path` in CSS to draw the required shape to fit the text content; without the need for a background image, eg:

**style.css / style-editor.css**

```css
.green-background {
    position:relative;
    width: fit-content; /* to only cover the text */
    float: left; /* default is centered in the Cover block */
    z-index:0;
}
.green-background::before {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    clip-path: polygon(10% 0%, 100% 0, 90% 100%, 0% 100%); /* background rectangle shape */
    background-color:rgb(115,213, 54); /* green color */
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Example Cover block with background image, color overlay with Additional CSS `green-background` applied only to Paragraph:
[image: Additional CSS on Paragraph in Cover block]

**NB.** The caveat to this method is that the Paragraph block can still override/apply its own text and background color: if a paragraph background color is picked it will appear over the top of the green background shape. If this is a concern, there are other steps you can take like extending the Cover block to remove the option.